# Procedure to refresh MySites content database in dev with production data

Tags: 2016, content-database, mysites

I would like to know the appropriate procedure to refresh MySites in dev by using a production content database backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, the two farms on the same domain, it is considered a simple

- **`Backup`** ,
- **`Dismount`** ,
- **`Restore`** ,
- **`Mount`** ,

Operations for the MySite Content Databases that hold site collections for each MySite.

---

**In Production farm,**

- Specify the MySite web application and its content databases.
- Open SQL Server Management Studio, Backup the content databases.
- Move it to the Test DB Server.

**In Test farm:**

- Specify the MySite web application and its content databases.
- Dismount the current MySite web application content database.

  ```
    Dismount-SPContentDatabase "My Siye content database name"
  ```
- Open SQL Server Management Studio, Take a database backup for the MySite web application content database to enable the rollback if the migration process failed.

  - De-attach the MySite Content database
  - Restore the Production MySite database backup.
- Mount the New MySite content database for the web application.

  ```
   Mount-SPContentDatabase "" -DatabaseServer "" -WebApplication http://web app
  ```
- Test the mounted content database.

  ```
   Test-SPContentDatabase "content database name"
  ```
- Verify that the My Site Host URL field on the User Profile Service application has the correct URL users should use to access the My Sites web application.

Comment: Hi, I followed the steps, ran the Mount-SPContentDatabase with the new DB and performed Test-SPContentDatabase successfully, the new database reflects correctly on the command prompt Get-SPContentDatabase. But on Central administration page, it is still showing the old content database, and the site collections does not appear. Can you please advise in this case?